# react hot reloading issues using ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-loader

I have the following two react components, one is the main App and the other one is a notification component which uses react-notification-component. I omitted some parts of the code which I thought are not that important.

Please notice the logs.

```
import ReactNotification from "react-notifications-component"

function App() {
  const notificationDOMRef = useRef(null)
  return (
                <>
                    <ReactNotification ref={notificationDOMRef} />
                    {
                        notificationDOMRef && 
                        <Notification notificationDOMRef={notificationDOMRef}>
                        ...
                        </Notification>
                    }
                </>
  )
}



export const NotificationContext = React.createContext();

function Notification({ notificationDOMRef, intl, children }) {
    const [actions, setActions] = useState(null)
    console.log("Notification");

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Effect");
        const pushNotification = (errorType) => notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification(errorType)
    }, [])

    return (
        <NotificationContext.Provider value={{actions}}>
            {children}
        </NotificationContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

The following scenario happens only when development environment is running. Hot reloading is enabled.

When I start the development environment and run a query that is successful, a green box appears notifying me. In this process only one `Effect` keyword is printed.

Now if I change something in the code, for example changing the string `Effect` into `Eff` and save, the application reloads but when I click the save button I get an error which says: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addNotification' of null` in the `pushNotification`. If I try to debug in Chrome, the `addNotification` function is present on the `context` but the application sees it as null.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong or this is an issue with the hot reloading?

PS: the `useEffect` is necessary because I am setting only once (when initialized) some `axios` interceptors.

PS2: if I disable the hot realoading, the page refreshes completely and everything works fine. So the problem is only in dev mode.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "react-hot-loader": "4.6.5",
    "webpack": "4.29.1",
    "webpack-cli": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-intl": "2.8.0",
    "react-notifications-component": "1.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution for this issue. I found myself in the situation to replace to use another library that doesn't make use of `ref`s.

I tried different hooks to handle the initialization, I tried removing all the hooks and moving to react components instead of functional components and the results were the same.

In simple scenarios the library could be good but I ended up using react toastify because I needed to create a brigde between axios interceptors, react intl, react and the toast lib.

Comment: Have you found any solution?